# PhpStorm. Disable CSS codestyle formatting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, phpstorm, vue-component

Currently I'm working with *Vue.js* components.

The problem is that I have such a style block

```
<style scoped>
    .some-class >>> .multiselect__tags {
        /*...*/
    }
</style>
```

and *PhpStorm 2017.3.6* is constantly converting it into

```
<style scoped>
    .some-class > > > .multiselect__tags {
        /*...*/
    }
</style>
```

what is, obviously, an error, cause `>>>` is a *Vue.js*-specific combinator. More about it [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

Did I miss a solution except for the `/deep/` combinator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to upgrade your IDE to next **2018.1 version** -- it was fixed there (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26828)

- WebStorm 2018.1 is already released
- PhpStorm 2018.1 will be released soon (expected this week)

You may use [Release Candidate build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/03/phpstorm-2018-1-rc/) meantime if you need this functionality right now in PhpStorm.

Comment: Just a small note. PhpStorm has just been released. Works as expected.